# Non-negative bivariate polynomials in a rectangle

Tags: polynomials, semidefinite-programming

I have been working on non-negative univariate polynomials and I found the following equivalent relationship to check if a polynomial is non-negative or not:

> The polynomial $g(x) = \sum_{r=0}^k y_rx^r$ satisfies $g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ if and
> only if there exists a positive semidefinite matrix $X = [x_{ij}]_{i,j=0,...,k}$, such that
> \begin{equation*}
>     \sum_{\substack{i,j=0,\ldots,k \\ i+j=2q-1}}x_{ij}=0, \qquad q=1,\ldots, k
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
>     \sum_{\substack{i,j=0,\ldots,k \\ i+j=2q}}x_{ij}=\sum_{m=0}^q\sum_{r=m}^{k+m-q}y_r {r\choose m} {k-r\choose q-m}a^{r-m}b^m, \qquad q=0,\ldots, k.
> \end{equation*}

This result is found in
Bertsimas, D., & Popescu, I. (2005). Optimal inequalities in probability theory: A convex optimization approach. SIAM Journal on Optimization, 15(3), 780-804.

I was wondering if this result (or any other, preferably using semidefinite programming) have been extended to bivariate polynomials, that is to say, if someone can find conditions for a bivariate polynomial $g(x,y)=\sum_{r=0}^k\sum_{s=0}^l a_{r,s}x^ry^l$ to be non-negative over some rectangle $[a,b]\times [c,d]$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd expect that the polynomial is positive on $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ iff it can be written as a polynomial with positive coefficients in $x-a$, $b-x$, $y-c$ and $d-y$.